# How to send an image via Node.js/Express, so it is cached permanently?

Tags: node.js, http, express

What are the required http headers to tell the browser to cache an image forever, when sending it via Node.js?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790825/nodejs-express-framework-caching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
if (!res.getHeader('Cache-Control') || !res.getHeader('Expires')) {
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=345600"); // ex. 4 days in seconds.
    res.setHeader("Expires", new Date(Date.now() + 345600000).toUTCString());  // in ms.
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this only caches for 4 days, right? That doesn't seem all that permanent to me.