# Cache text responses in browser

Tags: node.js, http, caching, browser

The scenario is the following:

1. The request comes on server side.
2. The server gets the content of a file and modifies it, computing the information that comes from request.
3. The server sends the response sending the computed information (string) using `response.end(content)`.

Is it possible to cache such response in browser?

Right now, I only cache in browser files (images, CSS & HTML files etc) that are streamed using `stream.pipe(response)`. I use `stats = Fs.lstatSync(fileName)` to get stats about the file. Caching stuff code is [located here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-statique/blob/995b0b97f430c82ba61f2c18f6b6fde486409671/index.js#L239-L277).

If the response is just text, I cannot have any stats, because I don't have a file but a long string.

How can I cache text responses? How can I handle them modifications?

Comment: Just to make sure: whenever you hit `/url1`, the response will always be the same?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine In the most of cases yes. That's why I am asking how to handle modifications. But basically, yes.

Comment: For a browser, knowing whether to cache or not depends on the url, not on the request body. So you have to make sure that the url **always** returns the same response.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine OK! Let's suppose that. It would be perfect in my case.

Comment: Then simply set the cache header on the response. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8007793/851498)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Is that enough? I suppose there should be a `304` response also (when the content is already cached).

Comment: I think that is managed by node itself. Try to keep the headers and body same. If the etag remains same it will send 304 automatically.